# Swipe in PageView when a widget is in front of it in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-pageview

i have a Stack and a PageView inside it. there is some other widgets in front of my PageView in Stack. something like this:

```
Stack(
  PageView(...),
  Container(...),
  Text(...),
  ....
),
```

now if i try to swipe PageView if my finger touches other widgets swiping stopes and dosent work.

how can i make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI priority on Widget tree is bottom to top, means while rendering the `Stack` widget, `PageView` widget is placed the last layer, that's why you are facing with swipe issue. You may have good reason to put other's widget before `PageView`. To solve this, you can use another `GestureDetector` as the last Widget on `Stack` children and use `PageController` to switch between pages.

```dart
Stack(
  PageView(...),
  Container(...),
  Text(...),
///  .... 
    GestureDetector(),///* you can test and set animation, direction, duration etc
),
```

***Full widget***

```dart
class SwapPV extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwapPV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwapPVState createState() => _SwapPVState();
}

class _SwapPVState extends State<SwapPV> {
  PageController controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        PageView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(.2),
          child: Text("OverLap Container"),
        ),
        Align(alignment: Alignment(0, .1), child: Text("Another OverLapText")),

        ///THis will controll the PageView
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            // Swiping in right direction.
            if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
              controller.nextPage(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeIn);
            }

            // Swiping in left direction.
            if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
              controller.previousPage(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut);
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```